# Keywords with spaces in Listings

Tags: spacing, listings, input-encodings, microtype, keywords

I want *spaced keywords* in `listings` (that is, keyword, with spaces in between).

Now, there are some questions in this site already answered, [like this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/27653/21930), where the official answer is that [“it is not possible”](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/27684/21930). But, of course, like almost everything, there are [workarounds that let you do it](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/154257/21930).

However, I've seen in the documentation of [`microtype`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/microtype/microtype.pdf) correctly highlighted keywords that *do* contain spaces (e.g., `no ligatures`, `outer kerning`, `outer spacing`).

That's all. If I didn't make myself clear, please, leave a comment. That's the question: *I want to reproduce the system used in `microtype`'s documentation*.

---

## Update

As @Robert noted, he used `latin1` encoding in the documentation. Which seems to work nice with `lstlisting` (apart from non-breaking spaces, it even accepts, e.g., `á`, `ü` by default). But I use `utf8` (not for anything special, but because it's recommended everywhere), which doesn't behaves well with `listings`. Since I like this idea of using non-breaking spaces to define keywords with spaces, I will rewrite my question

### Is there a way to teach `utf8`/`listings` to *understand* non-breaking spaces inside of keywords?

Here is a minimal non-working example:

**NOTE:** the space between `spaced` and `keyword` is a non-breaking space (as you can see in the image below).

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenx} % With latin1 it works perfectly

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{keywords={spaced keyword}, columns=fullflexible}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
  notakeyword spaced keyword notakeyword
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If you think the question is unclear, feel free to edit ;)

Comment: I don't think there is a workaround for this. `listings` only allows ASCII characters in keywords, and the non-breaking space is an extended-ASCII character (its decimal code is in [128,255]). Highlighting keywords containing ext.-ASCII chars involve that kind of dirty and far-from-optimal tricks: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/122850/how-to-insert-a-keyword-with-accents-extendedchars-in-listings

Comment: But then, how does microtype.dtx work?

Comment: The premise of your question is wrong: the file used to generate the `microtype` manual ([`microtype.dtx`](http://ftp.heanet.ie/pub/CTAN/tex/macros/latex/contrib/microtype/microtype.dtx)) doesn't use `listings` at all for typesetting "outer spacing", "outer kerning", "no ligatures" as shown on p17 of that manual. Instead, this is done via a macro called `\key` defined with `\DeclareRobustCommand\key[1]{\textcolor{thered}{\ttfamily#1}}` in [`microtype.dtx`](http://ftp.heanet.ie/pub/CTAN/tex/macros/latex/contrib/microtype/microtype.dtx). No non-breaking space is involved or necessary for that.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm not referring to that (I think). I'm referring to the page 17 on the top, the code shown (I will upload a picture). However, in case I'm still wrong, please, search through the document for non-breaking spaces to see where I'm refering to (again, that might not be a non-breaking space, but I think it is). I will upload a certain part of code of the .dtx (I don't know how dtxes work, so I will upload the raw —commented— code).

Comment: To all of you who voted to close, please, feel free to comment here your doubts or point out what is not clear.

Comment: Now I see what you mean. I think I was looking at the wrong page of the manual. For information, TeX.SX "sanitizes" the text you paste in the answer box; for instance, tabs get converted to 4 spaces. I didn't know it also converts non-breaking spaces to spaces.

Comment: The author of `microtype` is a contributor to TeX.SX. I'm sure he's the best person to answer this.

Comment: That's great. Should I mark it with `microtype` label to draw his attention?

Comment: Yes, definitely.

Comment: You need to load `inputenc` with an encoding that (1) contains the non-breaking space and (2) is not `utf8` because `listings` won't like it. (`microtype.dtx` uses `latin1`).

Comment: @Robert Well, that's an answer ;) I totally missed that. However, everywhere you look `utf8` is recommended (and that's the *only* reason I use it). (1) Is it possible to teach the non-breaking space to `utf8`? (2) Is there a workaround so that `utf8` won't collide with `listings`? You can post an answer, but I will wait a little more to see if someone offers a solution.

Comment: @Manuel Yes, you can use `linstings` plus UTF8. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/176694/non-ascii-character-as-argument/193954#193954 including my first comment about LaTeX usage of encTeX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, most of your questions have already been answered either in the question itself or in the comments, so here's just a recap to satisfy the site's mores:

- The workaround to allow spaces in keywords that `microtype.dtx` employs is to use the "non-breaking space" in lieu of a normal space to make `listings` believe that it's a letter, while it will be output as a space;
- this requires loading an input encoding that does indeed contain the non-breaking space and maps it to a normal space (e.g., `latin1`).
- The problem in your example is that you use `utf8` input encoding, which – though it meets the above requirement – is not compatible with the `listings` package. I don't see a way to fix this incompatibility other than in `listings` itself.

AFAICT, you only have two options:

- either don't use `utf8` encoding – which in your case appears to be possible considering the fact that you say the only reason why you use it in the first place is that it is recommended everywhere;
- or use the `listingsutf8` package (which understands `utf8` input in included files) and store all your code listings in separate files – maybe a bit cumbersome depending on the number of listings you have.